# What is the difference between AppKit and UIKit?

Tags: ios, macos, uikit, appkit

UIKit and AppKit still share a lot of concepts. Apple says:

> [AppKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit) contains all the objects you need to implement the user interface for a macOS app—windows, panels, buttons, menus, scrollers, and text fields

They also say that UIKit is used to implement the user interface:

> [UIKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/) provides the window and view architecture for implementing your interface

So what's the main difference between these two framework?

Comment: AppKit for macOS, UIKit for iOS. That's the main difference.

Answer (score 11):

**AppKit**
AppKit is included in the OS X SDK only. It provides all the classes and controls you need for creating Mac applications. Most of these classes share a common naming prefix starts with NS and classes you will be working with include - NSView, NSButton.

**UIKit**

UiKit is the framework that iOS uses to provide its UI and its classes start with a UI prefix. For example, both frameworks have a class to represent color include UIColor, while other concepts are pretty unique to UIKit, such as its use of predefined controllers such as UINavigationController and UITabBarController

Comment: `NSString` and `NSObject` are not declared in `AppKit`, so they are kind of bad examples of "classes you will be working with". They are `Foundation` classes.

Answer (score 8):

AppKit is much older and was developed for desktop machines, like Macintosh (Mac OS X) and (before that) NeXT.

UIKit is later, a deliberate reduction and rationalization of AppKit, developed for iPhones (iOS).

Answer (score 4):

AppKit is for MacOS[Cocoa] and UIKit is for iOS[Cocoa Touch]

Answer (score 1):

They are the same UI framework except that UIKit's views and controllers were specifically made for touch, while the AppKit equivalents were specifically made for the mouse or non touch .