# How to always show right most part of NSTableView header text?

Tags: swift, header, nstableview, appkit

Let's say I have a `NStableView` column with `ThisIsMyVeryVeryLongName` header title.
When I reduce the width of column by resizing, it usually shows like this `ThisIsMyVery...` (showing extra info is on the right side).

How do I change this to `...VeryLongName` upon column width reduction.

(`right` alignment doesn't seem to work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On UILabel you can set Line break to `Truncate Head`. This will do what you need.

yourLabel.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingHead

Comment: `UILabel` and `NSTableView `? iOS or macOS?

Comment: NSTableView is macOS, and UILabel is iOS

Comment: Does the header of `NSTableView` contain `UILabel`s?

Comment: No macOS doesn't use UIKit , so UILabel isn't really an option (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51517510/what-is-the-difference-between-appkit-and-uikit) . In my reply to the main question I had a feeling they were developing on iOS, so I suggested the UILabels lineBreakMode. Hope this helps, but I'm not too familiar with macOS